# Hide games in "apps" in Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I'm hoping for a way for Play store to stop promoting games to me all over the place. I don't mind them listed in the Games category, but I can't stand to have them in the Apps category. Any way to do this?

Using play store ver. 5.3.6

Answer (score 2):

The playstore app will not show any games if you open it with this link: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/APPLICATION

I hope that it becomes accessible from inside the app one day.

[Source](https://m.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3ikv0i/google_play_store_needs_an_option_to_hide_games/cuhs2t6)

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt anything can be done about that in the playstore app. But you can switch to a different front-end at least for your "store browsing" experience (see e.g. my app list for [App Markets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets)). A good choice should e.g. be [AppBrain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps): Less clutter, more features.

[image: AppBrain] [image: AppBrain] [image: AppBrain]
<sup>Screenshots of the *AppBrain Market* app (click images for larger variants)</sup>

You could even disable updates and update checks in the original Playstore app, and let *AppBrain* take care for it. That way you can decide which apps should be monitored, skip single updates (and only be notified for the next) or all of them for a given app altogether. And more. For app the installation process (incl. updates) itself, you still will be redirected to the Playstore app – so it really is "just another window to the same market place".

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it seems that in AppBrain you can't hide games either...

Comment: Uh? It's been quite a while since I've used it last – but apart from the Games category, I don't remember any such disturbancy. So maybe that's changed – sorry for that then!